# lauching different activities depending on a value

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I'm trying to start a new activity depending of the value of a parameter when the user clicks the next button

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/next" />
```

I think I shouldn't use the code I know to launch a new activity, because it launchs only a single activity.

```
android:onClick="lanzarActividad"
```

My purpose is that user sets a parameter (a number) and each number corresponds to different activities.

I guess I should write something similar to that (in onCreate method)

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
int parameter=1;
//it already contains a number, in our case, it might be for instance 1
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            switch(parameter)
            {
            //Now I get the problem.
               case 0 : 
               lanzarCalculate(v);

               case 1 :
               lanzarCalculate2(v);
            }
        }
    });
```

The methods that creates the intents are

```
public void lanzarCalculate(View view)
//si apretamos el boton calculate
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Calculate.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putDouble("time", tau);
    i.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void lanzarCalculate2(View view)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Calculate2.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putDouble("time", tau);
    i.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

enter code here

Thank you very much, I hope you can help me.

Comment: @user2374720 Please tell what is the problem you are getting.

Comment: Are you telling us that you are insecure of your actions? Why don't you try your method, it's not like you are going to build a nuke :)

Comment: I don't know how to launch the activities. I mean, I don't know the java code that follows after case x: 
I've tried to do that with the following code (calling the methods that starts the new activities), but it does not work
`code`
switch(option)
{
//Now I get the problem.
case 0 : 
launchActivity1(v);

case 1 :
launchActivity2(v);
}

Comment: You should have told us that in the beginning :)

Comment: sorry, I'm going crazy and I don't know why my program exits when I call those methods  :S

Comment: @user2374720 see my answer. I think it will work nicely for what you want. I've added comments in the code as I think it will explain it better to see what is happening throughout

Comment: You should be using `YourActivityName.this` instead of `this` when you create your `Intent`. Also, passing the `View` to the function shouldn't hurt but looks unnecessary in this situation. Also, you are reusing code in the functions that you don't need to. Again, not going to hurt but can be more efficiently written is all

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try to do that. I'll write back if I can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are unsure of how to use the Intent "dynamically". This is how I have done it to keep from repeating code

```
@Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();        // first, create your Intent object
        String nextAct = null;               // name for Activity to start with Intent
        String package = "com.my.package.";  // set package name
        int flag = -1;                      // in case you want to set certain flags depending on activity

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case (R.id.logout):            // mine are menu options so you will use the ints that you have already
                nextAct = package + "LoginScreen";
                flag = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP;
                break;
            case (R.id.changeLocation):
                nextAct = package+ "ChangeLocation";   // package is reused but in some cases it different for me
                break;      
            default:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item currently not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        try 
        {
            if (nextAct != null)
            {
                intent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, Class.forName(nextAct));  // change the String that I was setting to the Activity name
                if (flag != -1)
                {   intent.setFlags(flag);  }  // set my flags if I had any
                startActivity(intent);  // start the Activity as you normally would
            }
```

This is for a PopupMenu but you can do the same thing in your `onClick()`. I have added comments in the code to help explain what its doing.

Also, this

```
android:onClick="lanzarActividad"
```

would be fine in your xml. With this, you just wouldn't need to define your `Button` and listener

```
public void lanzarActividad(View v)
{
    // code from above
}
```

This function will be called and run when you click your `Button`

**Edit**

It seems your underlying problems are you need to use `YourActivityName.this` instead of `this` when you create your `Intents`. Also, add `break;` statements in each case or it will go on and run the next `case`. But the above code will keep you from needing to rewrite the `Intent` code since most of it is the same

Comment: I've done that before....but it does not work....Please, take a look to the question (I've added what I've tried to do)

Answer (score 1):

This is explained nicely in the docs if you search for "start activity" http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Basically you need to create an `Intent`, and then call the `startActivity` method using the intent as parameter, for example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

See the doc page for more options and examples.

Comment: I've done that before....but it does not work....Please, take a look to the question (I've added what I've tried to do)

Comment: Have you declared the `Calculate` and `Calculate2` in your manifest? Can you paste the exception you get on logcat?